# How to call a function and change heading text and color depending on time of the day in React?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, jsx

I am trying to change both text and color in my h1 heading depending on the hour of the day.
With my code I get the error: "**Cannot set property 'innerText' of null**".
I tried to find out how to implement a function in the render part but without success.
Here is my code:

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const morning = { color: "blue" };
const afternoon = { color: "green" };
const night = { color: "grey" };
const date = new Date();
const currentHour = date.getHours();

function sayHello() {
  const heading = document.querySelector("h1");
  if (currentHour < 12) {
    heading.innerText = "Good Morning!";
    heading.style.color = morning;
  } else if (currentHour > 12 && currentHour < 18) {
    heading.innerText = "Good Afternoon!";
    heading.style.color = afternoon;
  } else {
    heading.innerText = "Good Night!";
    heading.style.color = night;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <h1 className="heading">{sayHello()}</h1>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Comment: after heading delcaration write```if (!heading) return null```

Comment: When I include that statement I get rid of that error but after I get an empty field in my h1 as a result. Thanks for helping me with the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't how you use react. You might want to try something like:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

function Hello() {
  const currentHour = new Date().getHours();
  
  const [color, greeting] = 
    currentHour < 12 ? ["blue", "Good Morning!"] : 
    currentHour > 12 && currentHour < 18 ? ["green", "Good Afternoon!"] :
    ["grey", "Good Night!"];


  return (
    <h1 style={{color}}>
      {greeting}
    </h1>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Comment: So the best practice is to use ? instead of if and else statements and to put a function in < /> instead of {} in render?

Comment: It's personal preference, but in my experience using the ternary operator usually makes code more declarative with react.

Answer (score 1):

Try writing it this way its will work ,you created a function but didn't call it too. Here is also another way to implement the above code

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

// Creating time variable 
const time = new Date().getHours();
let greeting = "";

// Creating a color variable
let colorStyle = {
color: ""
};

// The if/else statements
if (time <= 12) {
greeting = "Good Morning";
colorStyle.color = "blue";
} else if (time > 12 && time < 18) {
   greeting = "Good Afternoon";
   colorStyle.color = "green";
} else {
  greeting = "Good Night"; 
  colorStyle.color = "gray";
}

ReactDOM.render(
 <h1 className="heading" style={colorStyle}>
   {greeting}!
 </h1>,
 document.getElementById("root")
 );
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `useState` and `useEffect` hooks.

https://codesandbox.io/s/modern-fog-qyjn9?file=/src/SayHello.js:82-117

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const morning = { color: "blue" };
const afternoon = { color: "green" };
const night = { color: "grey" };

const SayHello = () => {
  const [helloText, setHelloText] = useState("");
  const [helloTextColor, setHelloTextColor] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    const date = new Date();
    const currentHour = date.getHours();
    if (currentHour < 12) {
      setHelloText("Good Morning!");
      setHelloTextColor(morning);
    } else if (currentHour > 12 && currentHour < 18) {
      setHelloText("Good Afternoon!");
      setHelloTextColor(afternoon);
    } else {
      setHelloText("Good Night!");
      setHelloTextColor(night);
    }
  }, []);
  return <div style={{ color: helloTextColor }}>{helloText}</div>;
};

export default SayHello;
```

Comment: Tried that but somehow color doesn't change. Thanks for help.

Comment: @Vukasin Please check once again. I fixed it for you

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Set Time interval also ,which run your script like after 1 minute or whatever you want to set , then you can just check time and change your state .Simple